# filtering 'get avatar' not working for me

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning how to develop with the wordpress api. I want to display my own avatars, so I am tapping into the 'get avatar' filter.

This is my code at the moment...

```
function set_profile_avatar($id='', $size = "96", $default = '', $alt = 'profile avatar', $avatar_class = 'profile-avatar'  ) {

    echo $id;

    //get current user id
    global $current_user; 
    if(!$id){ $id = $current_user->ID; }

    //set the default avatar img
    $default= get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/default.png';

    //check to see if user has set custom avatar
    $gravatar_pic_url = get_user_meta($id, 'display_pic_url', true);

    if(!$gravatar_pic_url){
            $gravatar_pic_url = $default;
        }   

    //return the complied img tag
    return ("<img src='$gravatar_pic_url' width='$size' height='$size' class='$avatar_class' alt='$alt' />");
}

add_filter('get_avatar', 'set_profile_avatar');
```

I am calling the function like so...

```
<?php echo get_avatar($pending_member->ID, '150'); ?>
```

I've echo'd out $id inside the callback function and what I am finding is a generated img tag in there. Why isn't my ID variable being passed to the function.

I am guessing I've messed up how the filter hook works.

Comment: You're not setting the params: `add_filter( filter, callback_func, priority, PARAMS )`

Comment: I changed it to `add_filter('get_avatar', 'set_profile_avatar', 10, 5);` and it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, it just popped at first glance. I remmember having problems with this too. `get_avatar` is a [pluggable function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), maybe be worth a look.

Comment: "This function is pluggable, however plugin authors wishing to change the gravatar output should use the get_avatar filter instead, for compatibility purposes." So you are right but they still recommend to use the filter. I just can't find any good examples of how to pass parameters correctly to 'filtered' functions

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the problem. The add_filter hook seems to be passing the output of the original function as the first parameter, so you just have to capture that even if you don't intend on using it.

This is the code now working

```
//filter for profile avatar pic
function set_profile_avatar($content, $id='', $size = '96', $avatar_class = 'profile-avatar', $default = '', $alt = 'profile avatar') {

    //get current user id
    global $current_user; 
    if(!$id){ $id = $current_user->ID; }

    //set the default avatar img
    $default= get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/default.png';

    //check to see if user has set custom avatar
    $gravatar_pic_url = get_user_meta($id, 'display_pic_url', true);

    if(!$gravatar_pic_url){
            $gravatar_pic_url = $default;
        }   

    //return the complied img tag
    return ("<img src='$gravatar_pic_url' width='$size' height='$size' class='$avatar_class' alt='$alt' />");
}

add_filter('get_avatar', 'set_profile_avatar', 10, 5);
```

Now when I call the get avatar function like so...

```
<?php echo get_avatar($pending_member->ID, '150'); ?>
```

It will return the custom avatar for that profile ID. You must account for the out put of the original function automatically being passed as that first parameter.

I hope this saves other developers a lot time.